# Merge the first elements in a list a tuples if the second elements are the same?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have a list of tuples:

```
[('Donald', 'PERSON'), ('Trump', 'PERSON'), ('enters', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('White', 'LOCATION'), ('House', 'LOCATION')]
```

and the output I want is:

```
[('Donald Trump'), ('enters the'), ('White House')]
```

The below code gets me closer to the wanted result, but I'm not really familiar with the groupby function yet.

```
mergedTags = []
    from itertools import groupby
    for tag, chunk in groupby(tagList, lambda x: x[1]):
        if tag != "O":
            tagMerged = " ".join(w for w, t in chunk)
            mergedTags.extend([tagMerged])
        else:
            #tagMerged = " ".join(t for t, w in chunk)
            for word, chunk in groupby(tagList, lambda x: x[0]):
                mergedTags.extend([word])

    print(mergedTags)
```

Comment: Why do you have a condition based on `'O'`?

Comment: The Stanford Entitiy Recognizer tags elements that are not recognized as 'O'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with *list comprehension* expression as:

```
from itertools import groupby
my_list = [('Donald', 'PERSON'), ('Trump', 'PERSON'), ('enters', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('White', 'LOCATION'), ('House', 'LOCATION')]

output_list = [tuple(i[0] for i in e) for _, e in groupby(my_list, lambda x: x[1])]
#                 ^ generate the desired tuple
```

where the value hold by `output_list` will be:

```
[('Donald', 'Trump'), ('enters', 'the'), ('White', 'House')]
```

Comment: Note: tuples will be merged only if they are together. `groupby` groups the consecutive elements. If there is a possibility of them being distributed; you will have to firstly sort the input list based on index one i.e. `sorted(my_list,key=lambda x: x[1])`